# Edge label distance from edge in TikZ-qtree

Tags: tikz-qtree

I'm making a tree using `TikZ-qtree`, and I need to put labels on my edges.  Right now it looks something like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
    [.$\alpha$
        \edge node[left, pos=.2]{\scriptsize $p$};
        [.\phantom{$\beta$} ]
        \edge node[left, pos=.6]{\scriptsize $a$};
        [.$\alpha$ ]
        \edge node[right, pos=.2]{\scriptsize $b$};
        [.$\beta$ ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Right now, the "a" is quite far from the center edge and the "b" is quite close to the rightmost edge:

[image]

Ideally, the "a" would be closer to the middle edge and the "b" would be slightly farther from the right edge.  Does anyone know how to make this happen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve better control over the positioning of these `node`s is to define them as `node`s outside of the `\Tree`, and then `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`. This library makes it easy for you to place `node`s relative to one another. Thus, I've defined the topmost part of the tree as a `node`, and defined the position of the others relative to it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree
        [.\node (alpha) {$\alpha$};
            [.\phantom{$\beta$} ]
            [.$\alpha$ ]
            [.$\beta$ ]
        ]

    \node [below left=.1cm of alpha, xshift=.05cm] {\scriptsize $p$};
    \node [below=.2cm of alpha,xshift=-.1cm] {\scriptsize $a$};
    \node [below right=.1cm of alpha, xshift=-.05cm] {\scriptsize $b$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Hopefully, the above code will give you a beginning idea of how you can control the placement of nodes with the `positioning` library. You may also want to look at section 16.5.3 of the [`TikZ & PGF` manual](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (p. 185), particularly if you wish to further tweak the placement of these nodes.